# Upload de Imagens com PHP - Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Estou precisando fazer o upload de uma imagem no MySQL, ou seja, o caminho da imagem, tem algum método prático de fazer?

Comment: Qual método vc ja tentou? poderia descrever essa abordagem?

Answer (score 6):

No [site oficial do PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php) tem este exemplo, que eu alterei um pouco pra colocar :

```
<?php
// Nas versões do PHP anteriores a 4.1.0, deve ser usado $HTTP_POST_FILES
// ao invés de $_FILES.

$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
print "<pre>";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
    // Chame aqui um insert no banco de dados. 
    // Deve ser salvo na coluna do banco a seguinte informação: $uploaddir . $_FILES['userfile']['name'])
    print "O arquivo é valido e foi carregado com sucesso. Aqui esta alguma informação:\n";
    print_r($_FILES);
} else {
    print "Possivel ataque de upload! Aqui esta alguma informação:\n";
    print_r($_FILES);
}
print "</pre>";
?>
```

Neste exemplo, a única coisa que você vai enviar pro banco de dados é o caminho da imagem.

Answer (score 1):

Gosto de utilizar uma class em php para efetuar upload e ao mesmo tempo redimensionar a imagem. Veja se este exemplo serve para você. 
Especificações:

1. Gera miniaturas (neste exemplo uma com largura proporcional de 640px)
2. Renomeia o arquivo para outro nome utilizando md5
3. Cadastra no banco de dados (com PDO, em caso de não utilizar PDO coloque mysql_query ou mysqli_query, o que vir ao caso).
4. Pode ser personalizado

## index.php

```
<?php
include_once ("Redimensiona.php");

if (isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao']=="cadastrar"){

    $foto = $_FILES['foto'];    
    $redim = new Redimensiona();
    $src=$redim->Redimensionar($foto, 640, "images");

        $cadastra = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tabela (campo) VALUES ($src) ");
        $cadastra->execute();

}

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Foto <input type="file" name="foto" /></label>    
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
    <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="cadastrar" />
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao']=="cadastrar"){
    echo "<img src=\"$src\">";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

## Redimensiona.php

```
<?php
class Redimensiona{

    public function Redimensionar($imagem, $largura, $pasta){

        $name = md5(uniqid(rand(),true));

        if ($imagem['type']=="image/jpeg"){
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagem['tmp_name']);
        }else if ($imagem['type']=="image/gif"){
            $img = imagecreatefromgif($imagem['tmp_name']);
        }else if ($imagem['type']=="image/png"){
            $img = imagecreatefrompng($imagem['tmp_name']);
        }
        $x   = imagesx($img);
        $y   = imagesy($img);
        $autura = ($largura * $y)/$x;

        $nova = imagecreatetruecolor($largura, $autura);
        imagecopyresampled($nova, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $largura, $autura, $x, $y);

        if ($imagem['type']=="image/jpeg"){
            $local="$pasta/$name".".jpg";
            imagejpeg($nova, $local);
        }else if ($imagem['type']=="image/gif"){
            $local="$pasta/$name".".gif";
            imagejpeg($nova, $local);
        }else if ($imagem['type']=="image/png"){
            $local="$pasta/$name".".png";
            imagejpeg($nova, $local);
        }       

        imagedestroy($img);
        imagedestroy($nova);    

        return $local;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Esqueci de reforçar a utilização da tag <meta charset="utf-8"/> para evitar problemas de codificação, utilize o arquivo do formulário.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function uploadImage($tmp, $nome, $width, $pasta) {
       $ext = strtolower(substr($nome, -3));
       switch ($ext){
           case 'jpg'  : $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp);break;
           case 'jpeg' : $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp);break;
           case 'png'  : $img = imagecreatefrompng($tmp);break;
           case 'gif'  : $img = imagecreatefromgif($tmp);break;
       }
       $x = imagesx($img);
       $y = imagesy($img);
       $height = ($width * $y) / $x;
       $nova = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

       imagealphablending($nome, false);
       imagesavealpha($nome, false);
       imagecopyresampled($nome,$img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $x, $y);

       switch ($ext){
           case 'jpg'  : imagejpeg($nova, $pasta.nome, 100);break;
           case 'jpeg' : imagejpeg($nova, $pasta.nome, 100);break;
           case 'png'  : imagepng($nova, $pasta.nome);break;
           case 'gif'  : imagegif($nova, $pasta.nome, 100);break;
       }

       imagedestroy($img);
       imagedestroy($nova);

    }
```