# Como inserir uma imagem no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Gostaria de adicionar imagens na tabela, nada muito complexo.

- Gostaria de adicionar o diretório se possível
- Esse banco não vai ter uma interface
- Gostaria de ver a imagem pelo select, mas acho que isso não é possível.

O que vocês acham?

Comment: Oi, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Por favor, dê mais detalhes sobre seu problema. Confira o guia [ask] e **[edit]e** a pergunta para melhorá-la.

Comment: Isto te ajuda ou responde a pergunta? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9540/upload-de-imagens-com-php-mysql/9579#9579 ou isso http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14240/atualizar-campo-longblob-e-possivel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há duas abordagens comuns para se inserir uma imagem no banco de dados:

1. Salva-se a imagem num diretório (ex.: `C:\imagens`) e no banco o nome do arquivo da imagem, para buscá-la mais tarde.
2. Salva-se a própria imagem no banco utilizando uma coluna do tipo `blob` (binário).

Em ambos os caso **não** é possível visualizar a imagem diretamente (atrvés de um select).

No segundo caso é preciso utilizar uma função/método que "converte" a imagem de binário para arquivo novamente, oque torna tudo mais difícil de implementar.

---

Confira esta pergunta aqui: *[É errado gravar byte de imagens no banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12687/errado-gravar-byte-de-imagens-no-banco-de-dados)*